# How to override CustomerStateRequestProcessor in broadleaf

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

How can I ovveride CustomerStateRequestProcessor#resolveAuthenticatedCustomer function in broadleaf?

I tried this:-

```
@Component("blCustomerStateRequestProcessor")
public class MyCustomerStateRequestProcessor extends
        CustomerStateRequestProcessor {

    @Resource(name = "blCustomerService")
    protected CustomerService customerService;

    @Override
    public Customer resolveAuthenticatedCustomer(Authentication authentication) {
        if (authentication instanceof OpenIDAuthenticationToken) {
            OpenIDAuthenticationToken openIDAuthenticationToken = (OpenIDAuthenticationToken) authentication;
            if (openIDAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated()) {
                return (Customer) openIDAuthenticationToken.getPrincipal();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return super.resolveAuthenticatedCustomer(authentication);
        }
    }

}
```

Added context component scan :-

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.security,com.mycompany.web.request.processor" />
```

This resulted in :-

```
 org.springframework.context.annotation.ConflictingBeanDefinitionException: Annotation-specified bean name 'blCustomerStateRequestProcessor' for bean class [org.broadleafcommerce.profile.web.core.security.CustomerStateRequestProcessor] conflicts with existing, non-compatible bean definition of same name and class [com.mycompany.web.request.processor.MyCustomerStateRequestProcessor]
```

I am trying to overrid **resolveAuthenticatedCustomer** method for OpenIdAuthenticationToken.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use component-scanning to redefine the bean, remove that annotation and do it via XML instead.

So your class definition would change to:

```
public class MyCustomerStateRequestProcessor extends
    CustomerStateRequestProcessor {

    ...

 }
```

And then in any of your applicationContext.xml files (except for the servlet one) add this:

```
<bean id="blCustomerStateRequestProcessor" class="com.yourcompany.site.web.MyCustomerStateRequestProcessor" />
```

Note that this pattern is the same for overriding any Broadleaf-defined beans.